# contextisolation is off in this electron file?

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm trying to get used to using the 'electronegativity' tool to look around inside opensource electron projects. Just to get familiar with it.

So I'm running it on a non-descript open source project, (this one if you would like to know https://github.com/hello-efficiency-inc/raven-reader)

```
──────────┤
│ CONTEXT_ISOLATION_JS_CHECK              │ /home/ask/Git/raven-reader/src/main/pocket.js     │ 11:23    │ Review the use of the contextIsolation option    │
│ HIGH | FIRM                             │                                                   │          │ https://git.io/Jeu1p                             │
```

This looks interesting, it tells me that there are some issues with the context isolation in the pcoket.js file at line 11.

This would in my mind indicate that I can find something like this:

```
contextIsolation: true
```

However, when I look in the code in the location that electronegativity indicates, I just find this:

```
const authWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  width: 1024,
  height: 720,
  show: true
})
```

And I can't find any mention of context isolation anywhere in the file. Does this mean that context isolation is finding something that isn't there? or is there something smelly in the creation of the Browserwindow?

Comment: Well, it tells you that `contextIsolation` is missing. This could be a security problem, hence the warning. Consult the [documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions) for more information on this. Any answer depends on what you actually do with this `BrowserWindow`.

Comment: hmm, yes but from my reading on it, is'nt contextisolation set to true by default? (https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/context-isolation)

Comment: Only if you're on Electron >= 12, according to the article you linked. It could either be that you've got a version of that repo that does not yet use Electron 12, `electronegativity` has not yet caught up with Electron's API, you've got a version of that tool that's not meant for Electron 12, or it does not parse the `package.json`. However, it certainly does not hurt to explicitly define that Electron should use `contextIsolation` (it's more obvious), which is also probably (from reading the linked documentation article) what that warning wants to tell you.